# How do I add an EventHandler for a custom control on a Form's designer?

Tags: c#

**Goal:**

FormA has CustomButtonA.
When I click CustomButtonA I want FormA to call MethodA

**Failed Attempt:**

On FormA's designer, I added:

```
this.instanceOfButtonA.Click+= new System.EventHandler(this.buttonAPressed);
```

On FormA I also added:

```
private void buttonAPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MethodA();
}
```

Result: MethodA was never called

**"Solution"**

On CustomButtonA I added

```
public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, System.EventArgs args);
public event EventHandler OnClickEvent = delegate { };

protected override void OnControlAdded(ControlEventArgs e)
{
     e.Control.Click += new System.EventHandler(Control_Click);
     base.OnControlAdded(e);
}

void Control_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
       OnClickEvent(this, new System.EventArgs());
}
```

In FormA's constructor I added:

```
this.instanceOfButtonA.OnClickEvent += (sender, args) => { MethodA(); };
```

As an alternative, I guess I could use a delegate so that buttonA can call MethodA instead of having to throw an event that FormA handles

**Question:**
Is there something I can do to make my failed attempt work?
I'm not really happy with how my solution works

Comment: you are subscribing to 2 different events... just do `this.instanceOfButtonA.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonAPressed)` . However remember adding custom code to the designer can get overwriten so you're best working with the designer and just double clicking the button to generate all the code

Comment: Wouldn't .Click function roughly the same as .MouseCaptureChanged? Attempt 1 and Attempt 2 were done in isolation.
  
Double clicking the control generates instanceOfButtonA_Load which I think hints I'm doing something wrong in my custom control (I am using UserControl as a base class, not Button)

Comment: If you have a Click Event and assuming it is raised at the appropriate time, just subscribe to it in the constructor in the non generated part of the partial class

Comment: @Dave Sorry, I think I might be misunderstanding something. Does this.instanceOfButtonA.Click+= new System.EventHandler(this.buttonAPressed); not subscribe me to the click event? I tried shifting it from the designer to the constructor but it makes no difference.

Comment: I thought that's what you wanted to subscribe to. Sorry, I must have misunderstood